Problem with LT3743
I am resuming a project in which I want to make an LED driver. I decided to use the LT3743 that supports up to 40 A, my LED works at 22.5 A (Luminus cft-90).
In my circuit the LED starts at maximum intensity without PWM, in this first instance everything works correctly, when the PWM starts, in the output current signal I see current overshoots and after a few ns, the signal stabilizes. Try varying the PWM frequency, VCH resistor and capacitor values ​​and the signal does not seem to improve. What am I missing?
I also tried directly starting the PWM in my circuit and the same thing happens. I attach my circuit in LTspice and the graph with the overshoots. I am using the modulation method directly on the LED cathode that appears in the datasheet. In it I did not find information about the overshoots that my circuit has. I would appreciate if anyone has experience working with this IC and can help me see what I am overlooking. I attached the image where you can see the overshoots and my circuit in LTspice.
The values ​​and components are those recommended by the manufacturer in its application note and/or calculated according to the data sheet.



Do you have any reason to suspect that these very brief current spikes are a problem? Or that they will even actually happen in the real world, which is filled with low-pass filters?
